# Drawing a basketball using Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

Could you help me to draw a basketball using latex. I tried this version but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shad[ball color=orange] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
    
    % Lines on the basketball
    \draw [line width=0.5mm, white] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm]; % Outer circle
    \draw [line width=0.5mm, white] (0, -2) -- (0, 2); % Vertical line
    \draw [line width=0.5mm, white] (-2, 0) -- (2, 0); % Horizontal line
    
    % Curved lines
    \draw [line width=0.5mm, white] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (-1.8,0.5) (-1,1.8) (0,2) (1,1.8) (1.8,0.5)};
    \draw [line width=0.5mm, white] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (-1.8,-0.5) (-1,-1.8) (0,-2) (1,-1.8) (1.8,-0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of this line is :

```
\shade[ball color=orange] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
```

It should work now

Comment: do you know if there is a clean way to draw more white lines on the ball?